# Update error elementary OS freya

Tags: updates

When  I try to update elementary OS it gives me this error:
[image: software updater error]

And in terminal it gives me this one:
[image: Terminal error]

But if I then use apt-get upgrade, it installs all updates.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: please copy and paste the error information instead of screen shot =)

Comment: please let me know your problem solved or not , If solved don't forget to accept it as answer , by clicking tick mark at left side

Comment: my problem is Imposible obtener http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release No se pudo encontrar la entrada esperada «main/binary-i386/Packages» en el archivo Release (entrada incorrecta en sources.list o archivo mal formado)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:versable/elementary-update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

This should solve your problem.

---

**General solution**:

**Failed to download repository information**
Check your Internet connection.

---

1. Open terminal and run `sudo apt-get update` then identify the errors.

   Once identified root cause of this update error, the next step is to remove them from the list of software sources.

   Use `software&Updates` or `/etc/apt/sources.list`  if you identified PPA.
2. One line solution:

   Open terminal and run:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

---